# Using xmlstarlet to parse out revision and file info from svn xml output

Tags: xml, svn, xmlstarlet

Given the following xml output from svn (via svn log --xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
  <logentry revision="111802">
    <author>author1</author>
    <date>2014-09-24T17:48:11.447209Z</date>
    <paths>
      <path kind="file" action="A">/project/trunk/subdir/TransactionInfo.java</path>
      <path kind="file" action="A">/project/trunk/subdir/Validation.java</path>
    </paths>
    <msg>added the start to the new Validation tool </msg>
  </logentry>
  <logentry revision="111801">
    <author>author2</author>
    <date>2014-09-24T17:32:51.129605Z</date>
    <paths>
      <path kind="file" action="A">/project/dispatcher/branches/EUROPA/docs/somefile.txt</path>
      <path kind="file" action="A">/project/dispatcher/branches/EUROPA/docs/plans.txt</path>
    </paths>
    <msg>add plan steps doc and jobs spreadsheet</msg>
  </logentry>
</log>
```

I am trying to produce output something like this. Notice the correct 2 files are listed under the correct revision.

```
111802 | author1 | 2014-09-24T17:48:11.447209Z | added the start to the new Validation tool
    /project/trunk/subdir/TransactionInfo.java
    /project/trunk/subdir/Validation.java

111801 | author2 | 2014-09-24T17:32:51.129605Z | add plan steps doc and jobs spreadsheet
    /project/dispatcher/branches/EUROPA/docs/somefile.txt
    /project/dispatcher/branches/EUROPA/docs/plans.txt
```

I use the following command, but instead I am getting all files from BOTH revisions. I believe my mistake is in the second -m parameter?

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m /log/logentry -v "concat(@revision,' | ',author,' | ',date,' | ',msg)" -n -m /log/logentry/paths -v "path" -n svnoutput.xml

111802 | author1 | 2014-09-24T17:48:11.447209Z | added the start to the new Validation tool
/project/trunk/subdir/TransactionInfo.java
/project/trunk/subdir/Validation.java
/project/dispatcher/branches/EUROPA/docs/somefile.txt
/project/dispatcher/branches/EUROPA/docs/plans.txt
111801 | author2 | 2014-09-24T17:32:51.129605Z | add plan steps doc and jobs spreadsheet
/project/trunk/subdir/TransactionInfo.java
/project/trunk/subdir/Validation.java
/project/dispatcher/branches/EUROPA/docs/somefile.txt
/project/dispatcher/branches/EUROPA/docs/plans.txt
```

As a side note thought I would share, this produces a new summary I have found very useful:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m /log/logentry -v "concat(@revision,' | ',author,' | ',date,' | ',msg)" -n svnoutput.xml

111802 | author1 | 2014-09-24T17:48:11.447209Z | added the start to the new Validation tool
111801 | author2 | 2014-09-24T17:32:51.129605Z | add plan steps doc and jobs spreadsheet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of the extra `-m` and change your second value to `paths/path`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m /log/logentry 
                     -v "concat(@revision,' | ',author,' | ',date,' | ',msg)" 
                     -n 
                     -v "paths/path" 
                     -n svnoutput.xml
```